# Can anyone identify this Visual Studio 2010 extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm not sure what extension is painting the "Comment Bubbles" seen in this screenshot.
[image]

I've gone through the extensions that I knowingly installed and do not see an option to turn it off.  Either it's coming from an extension I don't know about, or it's an option in one of the ones I looked at but missed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, what does it do? The comment bubbles extension? Looks interesting ...

Comment: It looks like it hides the leading ' in comment blocks and replaces it with the comment bubble on the first line.   My major annoyance with it is that it tends to partially cover up the first character of the comment, making it annoying to read.  It doesn't seem to actually /do/ anything other than be visually annoying to me.  Nothing happens when you click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's devExpress.  Go to DevExpress-> Options

Expand Editor -> Painting and then go to Comment Painter.  Uncheck enabled.